# Phoenix channels with Android client

Tags: android, sockets, elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I'm trying to create a websocket connection to my Phoenix app from an Android client. I'm trying to use [this library](https://github.com/dsrees/JavaPhoenixClient) but I'm running into [this issue](https://github.com/dsrees/JavaPhoenixClient/issues/29) and I'm unable to successfully join a channel.

Upon reviewing the source code of the above java phoenix client library, it looks like the initial request from the client to connect to the socket is made with `http` schema and not `ws` (the source code explicitly changes the provided url to make sure it always uses `http`). It's not clear to me how this would work without additional configuration in my Phoenix app: if a socket connect request is made to `http://localhost:4000/socket`, the request will fail because there is no route for `/socket` when the schema is `http`.

There's nothing in the library docs that says any additional config is required in my Phoenix app to make this work, but I don't see how it could work for the reason stated above.

Does a Phoenix app have built in handling for the connection upgrade, etc, required on handshake as specified [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers)?

As a note, I have no issues making websocket connections from my javascript web client to my Phoenix backend.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the default path for a channel `http://localhost:4000/socket/websocket` ?